# Only creates the added folder, but no files are uploaded in Windows

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7, files

I have added a folder outside the default folder. After a while it showed up on the website and after restarting the client on my machine it showed up there, too.

It says "File Sync is up-to-date" but none of the files in the added folder are being uploaded.

Edit: Here are some logfiles

[syncdeamon.log](http://pastebin.com/GhpyJDk3)

[credentials.log](http://pastebin.com/7qSZ1NqZ)

[controlpanel.log](http://pastebin.com/sNbg75xw)

syncdaemon-exceptions.log is empty

status.log

```
2011-10-12 21:32:41,460 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection lost
2011-10-12 21:34:42,111 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection made
2011-10-12 21:35:03,219 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection lost
2011-10-12 21:37:03,966 - ubuntuone.status - DEBUG - server connection made
```

and so on...

syncdaemon-exceptions.log.2011-10-11_23-34-29:

```
2011-10-11 23:32:25,861 - twisted - ERROR - Unhandled error in Deferred:
2011-10-11 23:32:25,861 - twisted - ERROR - Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twisted\internet\defer.pyc", line 361, in callback

  File "twisted\internet\defer.pyc", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks

  File "twisted\internet\defer.pyc", line 542, in _runCallbacks

  File "twisted\internet\defer.pyc", line 1076, in gotResult

--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "twisted\internet\defer.pyc", line 1020, in _inlineCallbacks

  File "ubuntuone\platform\windows\ipc.pyc", line 1140, in connect

ubuntuone.platform.windows.ipc.NoAccessToken: got empty credentials.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Everything works fine after I booted the machine this morning!

Should have known it, it is a Windows machine after all...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about Ubuntu One.

Have you visited the web interface https://one.ubuntu.com/files

If you try clicking on the folder name, it should open it (and expand its contents)

Edit 1:
Just as a side note:
You can only sync folders inside your home folder. This applies to both Windows and Ubuntu clients.

Edit 2: Are you running it across a proxy server?

Edit 3: Can you post the contents of AppData\Local\xdg\cache\ubuntuone\log please

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, the files are not there. The folder is about 200MB of documents and pictures so it should have taken some time to upload them. Still says: "up-to-date".

Comment: In response to your edit: no proxy server. The folder is a subfolder in my Documents folder. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Can you post the contents of: AppData\Local\xdg\cache\ubuntuone\log please. (You should remove any personal details if applicable)

Comment: I'd suggest you uninstall and start again.